# Setting the max-height of a flex Div with nested table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox

Hey I have a table that is nested in an , which in turn is nested in a div. I also have another div that should sit below. However this div seems to sit in the middle of the table. I would like to be able to set A max height on the div or card and have the table inside scrollable. Here is my code and a link to a plunkr to show what I am experiencing.

HTML:

```
<div layout="column" style="dislpay: flex;max-height:100px !important">
<md-card flex class="white-card" style="max-height:100px !important">
    <h3 class="no-margin">Table</h3>
    <table style="width:100%;max-height:38%" >
<thead >
<tr id="stack-list-header">
    <th >
        <span>Name</span>
        <i class="fa right" ></i>
    </th>
    <th >
        <span>Age</span>
        <i class="fa right" ></i>
    </th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index"
    >
    <td  style="width: 50%">{{person.name}}</td>
    <td   style="width: 50%">{{person.age}}</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
</md-card>



</div>

<div layout="column" style="dislpay: flex;max-height:100px !important">
<md-card flex class="white-card" style="max-height:100px !important">
        <h3 class="no-margin">New Div</h3>
     <p>This should it below the table</p>
</md-card>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

$scope.persons = [

  {
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },{
name : "Bob",
age : "dole"
  },
  ];
}
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/dbaoz1SjtPQdoCFyZ3xi?p=preview

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use overflow-y css propertie on your column div like so :

```
<div layout="column" style="display: flex;max-height:100px !important;overflow-y:scroll">
```

The max height care of the maximum size and if the list is higher it will show a scoll bar. (btw Beware of the spelling "dipslay" ;) )